# eSATA and SATA III

Tags: cable, adapter, sata

I currently have a SATA to eSATA adapter on a system with SATA II, but I'm going to be upgrading to a system with SATA III ports on the motherboard.

What I'm wondering is, if I connect the same back-plate to a SATA III port, will it provide the full speed, or will it be limited to SATA II speeds?

As I understand it the same SATA cables are used between SATA II and SATA III without issue (I've done this myself and got SATA III speeds from cables marketed as SATA II only), but I don't know if this applies for SATA to eSATA adapters. My particular adapter appears to just be an adapter cable fitted to a PCI bracket, with no obvious active components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This question depends entirely on how the adapter was made. If it has it's own circuitry and it was only made to SATA II specs, then yes, it will be limited.

Comment: Aw, beat me to it!

Comment: I managed to figure out where the backplate came from (not easy thanks to no markings of any kind) but it's a StarTech model which cites SATA III compliance on its product listing, so yeah it should be okay then.